# C# DropDownList SelectedValue is set but not saving?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropdownbox

I feel like I'm missing something really obvious. :)

C# ASPX page, testing in most recent version of Chrome.

Here's the relevant code:

```html
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="JobSearch.aspx.cs" Inherits="GCWebForms.Jobs.JobSearch" %>
<asp:Content ID="HeadContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="Head" runat="server">
    <style>
        a img{border: none;}
        ol li{list-style: decimal outside;}
        div#container{width: 780px;margin: 0 auto;padding: 1em 0;}
        div.side-by-side{width: 100%;margin-bottom: 1em;}
        div.side-by-side > div{float: left;width: 50%;}
        div.side-by-side > div > em{margin-bottom: 10px;display: block;}
        .clearfix:after{content: "\0020";display: block;height: 0;clear: both;overflow: hidden;visibility: hidden;}
        
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Content/chosen.css" />
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <div class="body-content">
        <div id="searchform" class="simplelayoutform">
            <div>
                <div>
                    <asp:label id="lblCustomerSearch" runat="server" Text="Jobs for Customer:" AssociatedControlID="cboCustomerID" />
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="cboCustomerID" runat="server" class="chzn-select" 
                        DataSourceID="DataSourceCustomer" DataTextField="CustomerName" DataValueField="CustomerID">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <gcctl:MyCheckBox ID="chkCustomersShowInactive" Text="Show Inactive?" Checked="false" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" />
                </div>
        </div>

[[cut - search results go here]]
    </div>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="DataSourceCustomer" runat="server"
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT NULL AS [CustomerID]
                    , NULL AS [CustomerName]
                UNION SELECT [CustomerID]
                    ,[CustomerName]
                FROM [dbo].[Customers]
                WHERE ((@ShowInactive = 0 AND IsActive = 1) OR (@ShowInactive = 1))
                ORDER BY CustomerName">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter Name="ShowInactive" Type="Boolean" ControlID="chkCustomersShowInactive" PropertyName="Checked" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="JQScripts" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function fixform() {
            if (opener.document.getElementById("PageForm").target != "_blank") return;
            opener.document.getElementById("PageForm").target = "";
            opener.document.getElementById("PageForm").action = opener.location.href;
        }
    </script>
    <script src="../Scripts/chosen.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> $(".chzn-select").chosen(); $(".chzn-select-deselect").chosen({ allow_single_deselect: true }); </script>
</asp:Content>
```

JobSearch.aspx.cs (relevant parts):

```html
namespace GCWebForms.Jobs
{
    public partial class JobSearch : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        int? iCustomerID;
        int? iStaffID;
        bool bolIsPostBack = false;

        //--------
        protected void SetIDs()
        {
            this.iCustomerID = null;
            this.iStaffID = null;

            if (Request.QueryString["customerid"] != null) //new customer
            {
                try
                {
                    this.iCustomerID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["customerid"]);
                }
                catch { }
            }

            if (Request.QueryString["staffid"] != null) //new customer
            {
                try
                {
                    this.iStaffID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["staffid"]);
                }
                catch { }
            }

            if (iCustomerID != null)
            {
                this.cboCustomerID.SelectedValue = this.iCustomerID.ToString();
            }

            if (iStaffID != null)
            {
                this.cboStaffID.SelectedValue = this.iStaffID.ToString();
            }

        }

        //--------
        protected void DoSearch()
        {
            //gvJobsDataSource.SelectParameters["CustomerSearch"].DefaultValue = cboCustomerID.SelectedValue.ToString();
            //gvJobsDataSource.SelectParameters["StaffSearch"].DefaultValue = cboStaffID.SelectedValue.ToString();
            //gvJobsDataSource.SelectParameters["ShowClosed"].DefaultValue = chkShowClosed.Checked.ToString();
            
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.cboCustomerID.SelectedValue.ToString()) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.cboStaffID.SelectedValue.ToString()))
            {
                SearchPrompt.Visible = this.bolIsPostBack;
                gvJobs.DataSourceID = "gvJobsDataSourceInit";
            } else
            {
                SearchPrompt.Visible = false;
                gvJobs.DataSourceID = "gvJobsDataSource";
            }
            gvJobs.DataBind();
        }

        //--------
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                SetIDs();
                DoSearch();
            }
            this.bolIsPostBack = true;
        }

        //--------
        protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DoSearch();
        }
```

Issue: When I run, for example, **http://*server*/Jobs/JobSearch?customerid=22**, it's supposed to load customerID 22 into a dropdownlist of customers. And then it's supposed to do a search on that customer. It does the first thing, but not the second.

That is, I can SEE that the customer with the ID 22 has been automatically selected in the dropdownlist. But when I step through the PageLoad routine, it runs `SetIDs()`, where it does set `this.cboCustomerID.SelectedValue = '22'`, but then when it runs `DoSearch()` and I put a watch on `this.cboCustomerID.SelectedValue.ToString()`, it returns `''`, and so no search is run.

Why is `this.cboCustomerID.SelectedValue.ToString()` returning `''` when I just set its value to `'22'`?

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you store the customerid in session and retrieve from session. DoSearch calls the PageLoad again and resets the value of drop down. In SetID something like this after checking for not null customer id Session[“customerid”] = customerid;

Comment: try to have EnableViewState="true" in dropdown list control?

Comment: You are only calling `SetIDs` when not post back (during initial load) but upon postback it is not called. Study what `IsPostBack` exactly means; this where your issue is. Also, you do not need `bolIsPostBack` because `Page.IsPostBack` has that info.

Comment: Once `SetIDs()` is executed completely `iCustomerID` and `iStaffID` gets there respective values from `Request.QueryString`. Doesn't make sense why you have used `this.cboCustomerID.SelectedValue.ToString()` and `this.cboStaffID.SelectedValue.ToString()` in  `DoSearch()` when you can use `iCustomerID` and `iStaffID` instead.